# Problem with creating form for the element's child in the ".each do |f|" structure (form for nested resource)  in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, postgresql, nested, datamapper

I have model Account, which `has n, :transfers`. 
In the list of all available accounts

```
<% @accounts.each do |acc| %>
  <%= acc.name%>
  <%= acc.value%>
<%end%>

#in the controller
@accounts = @owner.accounts.all( :name.not => nil )
```

I need to add an option of creating of a transfer from this account, something like that:

```
<%= form_for @new_transfer, :url => {:controller => "transfers", :action=>"create"} do |trans_form|%>
  <%= trans_form.text_field :amount %></br>
  <%= trans_form.text_field :to %></br>
  <%= trans_form.text_area :comment, :rows=>5 %></br>
  <%= submit_tag %>
<%end%> 

#in controller
@new_transfer = Transfer.new()
```

How should i declare the parent for this new children item? I've tried something like `<%= form_for acc.@new_transfer`, `@new_transfer = @accounts.each.transfers.new()`, `<%= form_for acc.transfers` or `fields_for`, but none of them seems to work. Will be thankful for any advice.

Comment: Do you want to specify an account for new transfers?

Comment: yes, new transfer should be created from an account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at the routes, you should consider having a nested route for the `transfer` model under `account`, and at the controller level scope the transfer calls to that account.

For example the routes

```
resources :accounts do
  resources :transfers
end
```

Then in your transfers controller with a before filter to find the account (for all but index actions) by `account_id`:

```
def create
  @transfer =  @account.transfers.new params[:transfer]

  ...

end
```

View:

```
form_for @account, @transfer do ..
```

More info on nested resources:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Comment: It seems the right thing to do, thank you. But how should I call for a single `@account`, if their listing is called by `@accounts = @owner.accounts.all` and only after that - by `@accounts.each do |acc|`?

Comment: I've tried `@account = @accounts.each
   @transfer = @account.transfers.new()` but that gave me the `no block given (yield)` error

Comment: I see your issue, try, acc, and acc.transfers.new

Comment: yup, this worked, as well as form_for([acc, @transfer]), thank you!

Comment: btw, i've just stopped on just the same problem, but with update action. how should i call in the same form for the single element, but not the new one?

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
form_for(acc, acc.transfers.build) do |f|
.....
end
```